# How can I read out a Site that is secured by a form - with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, authentication

I want to scrape the web for data behind this url. But its secured by a form.
How can it pass it with nodejs to read the data?

This is what I have (maybe wrong aproach):

```js
var request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
var request = request.defaults({
  jar: true
})

// request.get('https://bracke-igs.de/iserv/plan/show/Vertretungsplan%20Schüler%20heute').auth('myusername', 'mypassword', false)

request.get('https://bracke-igs.de/iserv/plan/show/Vertretungsplan%20Schüler%20heute').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.txt'));
```

Thx for your help!

Comment: Set up `request` to store cookies if necessary, then send a POST request that mirrors what the form does. After that, you can send GET requests.

Comment: You have to replicate the auth process. as @ChrisG mentioned, send a POST request to pass the form, save the token the server sends you as a response and use it to authenticate your next GET requests.

Comment: @ChrisG how do you mean that? I must understand what the form does and send mirror it with the login data?

Comment: Yes. Look at the form source code and you will see that it sends a POST request to `https://bracke-igs.de/iserv/login_check` with params `_username` and `_password`. Construct a POST request accordingly and send it.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much! Code ist working know.